# Execution Path Specific Breakpoint

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, breakpoints, callstack

I would like Visual Studio debugger to break within a function *only* when the call is from a specific sequence of callers. Is there a way to set such a breakpoint? Or perhaps some alternative hack?

I ask this in the context of native (C++) as well as managed (C#) code.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could set a [conditional breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) that utilizes the [System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28VS.80%29.aspx) class.

**EDIT**: GrayWizardx has pointed out in a comment that this may not be possible.  In that case you could cause your code to break programmatically:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Use StackTrace class in this conditional to determine whether or not to break:
    if (yourConditionIsTrue)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: As ar as I know CBP need to evaluate to true inline without instantiation (i.e. essentially static), not to mention it would be a heck of a CBP to write.

Comment: @GrayWizardx: That's true - it would be pretty kludgey. Hopefully my new suggestion is better.